# How can I generate a key pairing object result with lodash?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, functional-programming, lodash

I have the following array:

```
const ids = ["1234", "5678", "0987", "6543"]
```

And I need a function with lodash that returns:

```
const result = {"1234": { workId: null }, "5678": { workId: null }, "0987": { workId: null }, "6543": { workId: null }}
```

What is the way using lodash methods?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Why do you need to use lodash? You could do this easily with plain `forEach`

Comment: `const result = {}; for (const id of ids) { result[id] = {workId: null}; }`

Comment: `ids.reduce((a, k) => ({...a, [k]: { workId: null } }), {})` ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a lodash solution that uses [`lodash#invert`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#invert) and [`lodash#mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#mapValues)

```
const result = _(ids)
  .invert()
  .mapValues(() => ({ workId: null }))
  .value();
```

```js
const ids = ["1234", "5678", "0987", "6543"];

const result = _(ids)
  .invert()
  .mapValues(() => ({ workId: null }))
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{min-height:100%;top:0}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: `lodash` is pretty overkill for that.

You can use [`reduce` (link to doc)](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#reduce)... or its [plain JS equivalent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const ids = ["1234", "5678", "0987", "6543"]
console.log(ids.reduce((acc, key) => Object.assign(acc, { [key]: { workId: null } }), {}));
```

Note that I use a feature of ES2015 to dynamically set the name of the new key to add to the accumulator.